# "MessageEmbed field values may not be empty" discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

I'm currently making a discord bot using a node.js and I found a problem when I make kick and ban command. I'm tried to make sure discord embeds and I keep getting this problem.
Can someone help me?

This is a embeds code:

```
const kickembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Member Kicked')
.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
.addField('User Kicked', member)
.addField('Kicked by', message.author)
.addField('Reason', reason)
.setFooter('Time Kicked', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
.setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(kickembed);
```

And here is a Error Log:

`(node:2400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.`

````
    at Function.normalizeField (D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432:23)        
    at D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:452:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:451:8)        
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at MessageEmbed.addField (D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:257:17)
    at Object.run (D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\commands\kick.js:35:6)
    at Client.<anonymous> (D:\DATA\Discord Bot\Tutorial #2\index.js:51:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
ated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2400) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: Looks like someone of your custom fields is receiving an empty value. Make sure that all of your addField calls are passing a valid value (should be a string not empty).

Here is the function called by normalizeField

https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/1f8f3ab0f8dbd346154bbfa14a98726b8df25d57/src/util/Util.js#L393

Comment: When next asking a question it will be more useful to the people attempting to fix your problem if you showed where `message` and `member` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js doesn't allow you to use empty field values, from your code it looks like the error is caused by `message.author`, as it returns an `user` object and not a string, instead you should use `message.author.username` (which will return the username of the person who ran the command). It is advisable to use ternary operator to prevent causing this error in the future.

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const kickembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Member Kicked')
.setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
.addField('User Kicked', member.user.username ? member.user.username : 'unknown')
.addField('Kicked by', message.author.username ? message.author.username : 'cannot access username')
.addField('Reason', reason ? reason : 'No reason provided')
.setFooter('Time Kicked', client.user.displayAvatarURL())
.setTimestamp()

message.channel.send(kickembed);
```

Since you do not have the `user` variable defined in your question, i added one to the answer.